# Facebook Ads Api issues with CPC as bid_type parameter when creating ad groups

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

does anyone have the idea what exactly isn't working here and IF you noticed the exception I'm seeing? I wanted to prepare for October changes announced by FB and it seems that when creating ad groups one will need to use CPC/CPM as bid types, will need to define max bid differently etc.

Here's my call:

```
curl  -F "campaign_id=XXXXXXXX" -F "bid_type=CPC" -F "bid_info={'clicks':111}" -F "name=test" -F "adgroup_status=1" -F "targeting={'countries':['US']}" -F "creative={'title':'test','body':'test','image_hash':'cf689a9aed4769fc4c8192569fda9f5e','link_url':'http://mylink.com/','type':1}" -F "redownload=1" -F "https://graph.facebook.com/act_XXXXXXXX/adgroups?access_token=TOKEN"`
```

And here's a response from FB API:

```
[error] => stdClass Object
    (
        [type] => Exception
        [message] => Please specify the locations on Facebook where you want to show ad impressions.
        [code] => 1487027
    )
```

This does not happen when I use 1 as bid_type.

What do you think?

Comment: There is a currently open bug report about this, but the reporter marked it as confidential - disable the migration and use the numeric values for bid type and it should be OK- there's a fix being worked on

Comment: thank you igy, will do. for that matter, my app already works ok... just wanted to migrate on time.

Comment: in order to avoid posting yet another question related to october 2 changes, i'm having similar situation with using 'reach' instead of 'clicks' in above call. again, if I use max_bid field instead of bid_info, there is no problem creating a cpm ad. is this reported as well?

Comment: This bug is also the case for CPA ads.  I still need to set the bid_type = 9 after the October breaking changes migration.

Comment: yes... i found another one and reported it. Igy was right - we should continue using things as they are... still, October 2 changes should be November 2 changes :)